# Do I need to generate br and gz files for s3 and cloudfront?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, webpack, amazon-cloudfront

When I build my application using vue cli and webpack, I add two plugins:

```
new CompressionPlugin({
    filename: '[path].gz[query]',
    algorithm: 'gzip',
    test: /\.(js|css|html|svg)$/,
    threshold: 8192,
    minRatio: 0.8,
  }),
  new BrotliPlugin({
    //brotli plugin
    asset: '[path].br[query]',
    test: /\.(js|css|html|svg)$/,
    threshold: 10240,
    minRatio: 0.8,
  }),
```

These plugins creates br and gz file for each files webpack create. for example `app.css`:

```
app.a35d9d23.css
app.a35d9d23.css.gz
app.a35d9d23.css.br
```

Now I moved to serve the application in cloudfront and s3.

My question is do I need to generate those files and upload them to s3? or cloudfront and s3 know to serve themselves (they creates br/gz files)?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't generate the gz and br files, CloudFront won't use them. These files are useful when you use a webserver (apache, nginx) as they can be optimized to serve the precompressed files instead of compressing them on the fly.

When you use CloudFront, you can [enable compression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html) which automatically takes care of serving compressed files. There are some caveats though, like there is a file size limit and it only supports gzip, but on the other hand it's just a checkbox you turn on.